# Use of the Linux Crypto API for AES Encryption

Tags: go, encryption, linux-kernel

I have some issues in using the Linux Crypto API (User Space Interface) of the USB Armory Mk-II. I successfully made hash calculation but not aes encryption or decryption operations.

I am writing a go code that will use the API for AES encryption/decryption. I'm taking example on the following code to help me: https://github.com/f-secure-foundry/mxs-dcp/blob/master/dcp_tool.go. Everything is installed and  Here is a part of my encryption function:

```
    fd, _ := unix.Socket(unix.AF_ALG, unix.SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0)
    addr := &unix.SockaddrALG{Type: "skcipher", Name: "ecb-aes-dcp"}
    unix.Bind(fd, addr)

    KEY := "\x2b\x7e\x15\x16\x28\xae\xd2\xa6\xab\xf7\x15\x88\x09\xcf\x4f\x3c"

    err = syscall.SetsockoptString(fd, unix.SOL_ALG, unix.ALG_SET_KEY, KEY)

    if err != nil {
            return
    }

    //unix.ALG_OP_ENCRYPT = 0x1
    // from https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/unix#pkg-constants

    //ENCRYPT := "\x00"
    err = syscall.SetsockoptInt(fd, unix.SOL_ALG, unix.ALG_SET_OP, unix.ALG_OP_ENCRYPT)

    if err != nil {
            return
    }
```

The code stop running at `syscall.SetsockoptInt` and the error is "protocol not available".

I don't know where this come from and the Linux crypto API documentation (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.19/crypto/index.html) doesn't really help me. If I understand it, I have to make a syscall to tell I want encryption operation (`unix.ALG_SET_OP`, `unix.ALG_OP_ENCRYPT`). But this doesn't work.

Does someone have an idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you have to send the operation flag with the data. In this code https://github.com/f-secure-foundry/mxs-dcp/blob/master/dcp_tool.go, you generate a derived key by encryption (aes cbc) of a diversifier with the TEST_KEY. The function `DCPDeriveKey` will first open the socket then bind it and set the key. Before encryption, made by the function `cryptoAPI`, we have to send the `SYSACCEPT` flag to the kernel. The function `cryptoAPI` will send the operation flag and the data to the kernel and read the answer of the kernel.